# AmCharts v5 - Uncaught Error: You cannot have multiple Roots on the same DOM node

Tags: javascript, php, html, amcharts, amcharts5

I am trying to display 4 charts side by side. Each div has its own id and I have a filtering options that I have to choose from. When I first make the selections and click  submit all the charts are being displayed just fine. However, when I have to make a change on the filters and re-submit so that I can pull new the data from the server I keep getting "Uncaught Error: You cannot have multiple Roots on the same DOM node" error. I was able to dispose the root but this option only works when I have only one chart on my page.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#getReport").click(function() {

am5.ready(function() {

// Create root element
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element

$.getJSON({
async: false,
type: "POST",
url: "<?= SITE_URL . '/Reports/Report1/' ?> ",

success: function(data) {
$("#reportsDiv").show();
createData("chartdivEducation", data, "value", "name");

},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
console.log('Error');
console.log(data);
alert(xhr.status);
alert(thrownError);
}
});

$.getJSON({
async: false,
type: "POST",
url: "<?= SITE_URL . '/Reports/Report2/' ?> ",

success: function(data) {

createData("chartdivNat", data, "totalChildren", "nationality");

},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
console.log('Error');
console.log(data);
alert(xhr.status);
alert(thrownError);
}

});

function createData(div, data, value, category) {
var root = am5.Root.new(div);
// Set themes
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
root.setThemes([
am5themes_Animated.new(root)
]);
// Create chart
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/
var chart = root.container.children.push(am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
layout: root.verticalLayout
}));
// Create series
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Series
var series = chart.series.push(am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
valueField: value,
categoryField: category
}));

// Set data
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/pie-chart/#Setting_data

series.data.setAll(data);

// Create legend
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/percent-charts/legend-percent-series/
var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
centerX: am5.percent(50),
x: am5.percent(50),
marginTop: 15,
marginBottom: 15
}));

legend.data.setAll(series.dataItems);

// Play initial series animation
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/#Animation_of_series
series.appear(1000, 100);

}

}); // end am5.ready()
});

});
</script>
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="reportsDiv">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="tn-content">
<div class="tn-content-head">
<h3 class="tn-content-title">REPORT 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="tn-content-body">

<div id="chartdivEducation" style=" height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="tn-content">
<div class="tn-content-head">
<h3 class="tn-content-title">REPORT2</h3>
</div>
<div class="tn-content-body">

<div id="chartdivNat" style=" height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var root = am5.Root.new(div)` - you are doing that every time you call your `createData` function, so after your filtering, you are doing it again with the same div IDs you already used. Looks like the library doesn't like that, so you will have to store your created root instances somewhere, so that you can access them directly the next time, instead of trying to create them again.

Comment: Unfortunately same thing happens when I take the root initialization to a global scope. Instead of disposing the root I guess I have to update existing data with setIndex()  method. Now I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - how is this problem related to PHP? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: PHP cop is here!  don't you see what I have tried. I am using this chart as a part of my web development project so it is not an irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by saving the created roots in a global array. Whenever I needed to redraw the chart I would loop through the array and call the dispose() method.

I really don't like global variables but it seems like this is the only way to keep a record of the charts.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the same and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From amChart5 [docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/root-element/)

You can remove root by id like so

```
am5.array.each(am5.registry.rootElements, function(root) {
    if (root) {
      if (root.dom.id == div_id) {
        root.dispose();
      }
    }
});
```